# Can someone help me solve this problem with sets and power sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and let $f : A \rightarrow B$ be a function. We define
a function $f_P : \mathcal P(A) \rightarrow \mathcal P(B)$, where $\mathcal P(A)$ is the power set of $A$ (i.e. the collection of all subsets of $A$), by $f_P(S) = \{f(s) | s \in S\}$. We proved that if $f$ is a
bijection, then $f_P$ is also a bijection.
Assume that $f : A \rightarrow B$ is surjective but not necessarily injective. Is $f_P$ also
surjective?

Prove or provide a counterexample.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

$f_P$ will be surjective if $f$ is as for $T \in P(B)$ you have
$T = f(S)$ where $$S = \{a \in A \mid f(a) \in T\} = f^{-1}(T).$$

This is another way to say that $$f(f^{-1}(T)) = T$$ for any $T \in P(B)$ if $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is surjective $\implies A_b=f^{-1}(b)$ is a **non-empty subset of $A$** for all $b\in B$, 
 then for any $B'\subseteq B$, $$f_P^{-1}(B')=\{a\in A|f(a)\in B'\}=\bigcup_{b\in B'} f^{-1}(b)=\bigcup_{b\in B'} A_b \subseteq \mathcal P(A)$$ proving that $f_P$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

If $W\in P(B)$ we want to find $S\in P(A)$ such that $f_P(S)=W$.

As $f$ is surjective then for any $b\in B$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$; in particular for any $b\in W$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Therefore just consider $S$ defined as $f^{-1}(W)=\{a\in A| f(a)\in W\}$, which is the set formed by every element of $A$ whose image by $f$ is in $W$.